# converting flat JSON to parent child relational structure from another JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a JSON of flat structure and i  want to make it as parent child relational structure.

My JSON Structure some thing looks like this  as
1st point if any subpoint exist it is appended to the 1st point i.e, wherever the sub point is it appends to previous point

```
my input json
json format image===>https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xFJp.png

structure
{
  "0": "Points",
  "1": [
    "1. This is the first Point"
  ],
  "2": [
    "2. This is Second point",
    "(a) SubPoint of 2",
    "(b) Sub Point of 2",
    "(c) Sub Point of 2",
    "(d) (i) Sub Point of d",
    "(ii)Sub point of d",
    "(iii) Sub point of d",
    "(iv) Sub point of d",
    "(A) Subpoint of (iv)",
    "(B) Subpoint of (iv)",
    "(C) Subpoint of (iv)",
    "(D) Subpoint of (iv)",
    "(e) Sub Point of 2",
    "(f) Sub Point of 2"
  ]
}
```

```
 with open('ks.json','r') as fp:
    fil=fp.read()
    i=0
    for item in fil:
        print(item)
        regex=r"^[0-9]+\.\s.*"
        regex1=r"^\([a-z]\)\s.*"

            j=0
            sub = []
            for i in item:
                if sub:
                    match = re.match(regex, i)
                    match1=re.match(regex1,i)
                    if match:
                         Points[str(j)] = sub
                else:
                    if sub:
                        Points[str(j)] = sub
                    sub = [i]
                    Points[str(j)] = i
```

```
expected json output should be in this way

Notes

1. This is the first Point"
2. This is Second point"
    "(a)":["SubPoint of 2"],
    "(b) Sub Point of 2",
    "(c) Sub Point of 2",
    "(d) 
        (i) Sub Point of d",
        "(ii)Sub point of d",
        "(iii) Sub point of d",
        "(iv) Sub point of d",
            "(A) Subpoint of (iv)",
            "(B) Subpoint of (iv)",
            "(C) Subpoint of (iv)",
            "(D) Subpoint of (iv)",
    "(e) Sub Point of 2",
    "(f) Sub Point of 2"
```

input json:

Comment: Your json example is invalid please fix that and maybe we can help. Is the indenting important? That level of indenting is quiet difficult with your current format. It would be easier if you did more nesting.

Comment: Given expected output is normal, not in json structure. JSON structure should be in that way as parent and child relation@Syntactical Remorse

Comment: Your JSON input is not valid JSON... I didn't say the output is wrong...

Comment: Please Check the image on given link. also modified the original one